# While loop to get PHP data into two different tables in HTML

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, html-table

[image]

Using a while loop to get my data out from PHP will only show all my data is vertical in a table form.

How can I show the data in horizontal form:

[image]

```
 <?php
            while ($display = mysqli_fetch_array($link)) {
                if ($display['see_id'] % 2 == 0) {
                    ?>
                    <table border='0' width='550px'>
                        <tr height='50px' style="text-align:center">
                            <td><?php echo $display['name']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $display['video']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height='50px'>
                            <td><?php echo $display['description']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height='50px'>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

            <?php }}
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put some style in your table: style="width:50%; float:left"
With while loop, of course.

```html
<table border='0' style="width:50%; float:left">
  <tr height='50px' style="text-align:center">
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Video</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height='50px'>
    <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height='50px'>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border='0' style="width:50%; float:left">
  <tr height='50px' style="text-align:center">
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Video</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height='50px'>
    <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height='50px'>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```